# FETs transfer characteristics in 4 quadrants

Tags: mosfet, jfet, education, plot

Recently I was given a following problem on the test:

> Usually, transfer characteristic (Id(Vgs)@Vds) of JFET and MOSFET is plotted in the 2 quadrants. Plot it in all 4.

After the test we were not given any explanation of the problem and it wasn't in the course either.

I'm still wondering, how would it look?

Comment: For JFETs you'd get a similar picture for Id when Vds moves negative.

Comment: @Andyaka Similar in what way? Would it be symmetrical? Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Similar to when Vds is positive

Answer (score 1):

Some JFET characteristics can look like this for positive and negative Vds: -

[image]

Note that the device can be regarded as a variable resistor up to a limit. It applies when |Vds| is much less than half a volt. A good document from TI ([here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/70598/70598.pdf)) explains this: -

[image]

Comment: (+1) Good point at guessing. That's what I thought it was rquired, too. But the test question asked about "transfer characteristics", not "output characteristics". Poorly formulated question, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly the question doesn't make lot of sense.

A gut feeling tells me that the intent was to make the student ponder on the symmetry of the FET structure, i.e. to highlight the fact that most JFETs and some MOSFETs have source and drain terminals that are interchangeable.

Despite this, taken literally it doesn't serve that (guessed) purpose. In fact the transfer characteristic is a plot of \$I_D\$ versus \$V_{GS}\$ at constant \$V_{DS}\$ which is usually plotted only for negative values of \$V_{GS}\$ (assuming JFET N-channel device). What you get is a branch of parabola, as you probably know. Extending the range of \$V_{GS}\$ to positive values shows nothing interesting.

In particular, an actual JFET will have out-of-spec behavior, since for positive Vgs values (>~0.6V) the gate junction becomes forward biased and the component stops behaving in a useful way. The following LTspice simulation shows what I mean:

[image]
[image]

For an NMOS device you have nothing unusual, because there is no gate junction, so the Vgs range can go in either direction without problems (until you damage the device for excessive applied voltage!).

The question should have been better formulated, IMO, because it doesn't tell you exactly what you where required to do (besides mind reading!).